# LINQ to SQL query returning duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Premiums table that I attempting to query using the following LINQ-to-SQL:

```
var premiums = sourcePolicyContext.Premiums.Where(prm => prm.Policy_Number == "07748106");
```

This runs the following SQL against the database:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[Policy Number] AS [Policy_Number], ' + 
                           '[t0].[PremiiumType] AS [Premiium_Type], [t0].[Number], ' +
                           '[t0].[Effective Date] AS [Effective_Date], ' + 
                           '[t0].[Entry Date] AS [Entry_Date], ' +
                           '[t0].[Collision Premium] AS [Collision_Premium], ' +
                         '[t0].[Non Collision Premium] AS [Non_Collision_Premium], ' +
                           '[t0].[Tow Premium] AS [Tow_Premium], ' +
                      '[t0].[Other Coverage1 Premium] AS [Other_Coverage1_Premium] ' +
                    'FROM [dbo].[Premium Table] AS [t0]' +
                    'WHERE [t0].[Policy Number] = @p0', 
                   N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',
                     @p0=N'07748106'
```

This query returns two rows when run directly, as expected. It also results in two LINQ to SQL entities, however the data in the two entities is just duplicates of the first row in the SQL query results. Why might this be happening?

Comment: What does the code that uses `premiums` look like?

Comment: The code is just a test line. I have it breakpointed and force the evaluation of the query by expanding the results. I am testing it because I have code elsewhere in the system that iterates over a parent table to Premium, and iterates over each Premium in that parent table, then uses the premium values to perform a calculation. The calculation was producing invalid results due to this behavior.

Comment: Why is the query expected to return two rows when run directly?

Comment: Because the query `select * from [dbo].[Premium Table] where [Policy Number] = '07748106'` returns two rows. The two rows returned, by both that query and the stored procedure, are distinct from one another. Different premium values, different premium types, etc... However it seems that LINQ-to-SQL recognizes there are two results, but fills both resulting entities with the data from only the first returned row.

Comment: Which column in your table is the primary key?

Comment: @Harikawashi - Yeah, I'm with you on this one - I'm assuming the ORM entity is using `Policy_Number`, which has been stated is non-unique.

Comment: Premiums is unkeyed, it possesses a FK [Policy Number] to the PK [Policy Number] on the Policy table.

Comment: Actually I am sorry, strike that, I added keys in the ORM designer, against Policy_Number and Number

Comment: @X-Zero, yeah that's what I was thinking. Not sure how to correct it though, maybe you can improve on my answer below. I'm off to bed.

Comment: @Starr, if you don't mind, posting the table definition might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but if you haven't already, try giving the table a dedicated unique identity column and set it as primary key. Make sure your LINQ-TO-SQL definitions know about the primary key column.

Comment: That did it. Not sure why it was necessary, the natural key I set up in the ORM designer was already unique, so I shouldn't have needed a surrogate key. Thanks!

Comment: @Starr You're right, that should have removed the necessity for the natural key.  I'd check your `Equals()` method, and related definitions, just in case.  Also, what about implementing `IComparable`?

Comment: We had this problem, and found that someone had specified the wrong column as the primary key in the mapping.